# Converting python list to pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a problem converting a python list of numbers to pytorch Tensor : 
this is my code :

```
caption_feat = [int(x)  if x < 11660  else 3 for x in caption_feat]
```

printing caption_feat gives : `[1, 9903, 7876, 9971, 2770, 2435, 10441, 9370, 2]` 
I do the converting like this : `tmp2 = torch.Tensor(caption_feat)`
now printing tmp2 gives : `tensor([1.0000e+00, 9.9030e+03, 7.8760e+03, 9.9710e+03, 2.7700e+03, 2.4350e+03,
        1.0441e+04, 9.3700e+03, 2.0000e+00])` 
However I expected to get : `tensor([1. , 9903, , 9971. ......])` 
Any Idea?

Comment: It's just the [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), numbers are ok. However, you should probably use [`torch.tensor()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor) for construction of tensors.

Answer (score 15):

You can directly convert python `list` to a pytorch `Tensor` by defining the `dtype`. For example,

```
import torch

a_list = [3,23,53,32,53] 
a_tensor = torch.Tensor(a_list)
print(a_tensor.int())

>>> tensor([3,23,53,32,53])
```

Comment: It says "only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars"

Answer (score 5):

If all elements are integer you can make integer torch tensor by defining [`dtype`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch-tensor)

```py
>>> a_list = [1, 9903, 7876, 9971, 2770, 2435, 10441, 9370, 2]
>>> tmp2 = torch.tensor(a_list, dtype=torch.int)
>>> tmp2
tensor([    1,  9903,  7876,  9971,  2770,  2435, 10441,  9370,     2],
       dtype=torch.int32)
```

While [`torch.Tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor) returns `torch.float32` which made it to print number in scientific notation

```py
>>> tmp2 = torch.Tensor(a_list)
>>> tmp2
tensor([1.0000e+00, 9.9030e+03, 7.8760e+03, 9.9710e+03, 2.7700e+03, 2.4350e+03,
        1.0441e+04, 9.3700e+03, 2.0000e+00])
>>> tmp2.dtype
torch.float32
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> torch.IntTensor(caption_feat)

You can see the other types here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple option is to convert your list to a numpy array, specify the `dtype` you want and call `torch.from_numpy` on your new array.

Toy example:

```
some_list = [1, 10, 100, 9999, 99999]
tensor = torch.from_numpy(np.array(some_list, dtype=np.int))
```

Another option as others have suggested is to specify the type when you create the tensor:

```
torch.tensor(some_list, dtype=torch.int)
```

Both should work fine.